# Improving Velocity Estimation Using Multiple Sensors in a Dynamic System

Tags: signal-analysis, kalman-filters, control-systems, dynamic-system

I have a sensor reduction model which gives me a velocity estimate of a suspension system(velocity 1) .

This suspension system estimate velocity is used to calculate another velocity(velocity 2) via a transfer function/plant model.

Can I use velocity 2 to improve my velocity estimate (velocity 1) through Kalman filtering or through some feedback system.??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you have new data to merge in.
For instance if you have a sensor for Velocity 1 and a sensor for Velocity 2 and in addition a connection between Velocity 1 and Velocity 2 you can use Kalman.

Yet if you have only one sensor for Velocity 1 which with the transfer system you estimate the Velocity 2 there is no additional info to fuse in.

What might be done is that if you have information about the model of Velocity 2 in time you can use that (Though, the right thing to do would be reflect this model into Velocity 1 by the connection of the two, apply Kalman on Velocity 1 and from there infer Velocity 2).

Comment: Hi could u look at the image I added.Can I use kalman for this. Im sorry,controls is new to me could u tell me what "connection" are u talking about

Comment: Try to write the differential equation connecting the two parameters.